# SOAP SDL Resource ID #251

Tags: php, soap

I've never used SOAP before, and I'm getting this when I print out an array. Could someone tell me whether it's working, or not? I'm not sure what the Resource id stands for and I couldn't find an answer..

```
$this->client = new SoapClient("https://api.cvent.com/soap/V200611.ASMX?WSDL", array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true));
echo '<pre>';print_r($this->client);echo '</pre>';

SoapClient Object
(
    [trace] => 1
    [_soap_version] => 1
    [sdl] => Resource id #251
)
```

If anyone could help me out, that'd be great.

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: The problem was that the client didn't give me the API username / password. They gave me their cvent login information instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you solved your issue.
I went ahead anyway to figure out what sdl is and how to use it.

I checked the SOAP extension source code and it looks like the resource represents the parsed and interpreted WSDL which is used internally for near enough all the SoapClient methods to lookup and return definitions data.

[#L379 `le_sdl = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(delete_sdl_res, NULL, "SOAP SDL", module_number);`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/7bbc85f16ac7b54b3cdbadc787518aed33369b7e/ext/soap/soap.c#L379)

`le_sdl` is of type sdlPtr (service definition language pointer? ) and is referenced throughout.

**https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/7bbc85f16ac7b54b3cdbadc787518aed33369b7e/ext/soap/soap.c**

I have no idea why we can view this resource as a public property `SOAP_GLOBAL(sdl)`  as it doesn't look like it can be read by any PHP function.
Its not in the list of defined [resource types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php) and the [Soap documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.resources.php) clearly says that the extension doesn't have any defined.

> This extension has no resource types defined.